# How to set up the *.fbx scene to use it in Gear VR

Tags: 3d, gear-vr

I'm using a converter from Mobile oculus SDK to convert *.fbx file to *.overscene file. And then I'm using this overscene file in my app on Gear VR. And it is converted and loads without errors.

I'm not an expert on 3D graphics and I'm not sure how to dig deeper into the subject.

I was just using *.fbx samples I got from the internet. And I can see the objects in my Gear VR app. I tried to create my own *.fbx. And in gear VR app I can see my models but I have no idea how to set the background color to them.

Any ideas how to change this default green? ;) How should I set the camera and other settings in 3d studio max so that it would look good in Gear VR after conversion to *.ovrscene?

thanks

Magda